# How to escape or make a file path with a folder that contains a dot work in .yaml pipeline?

Tags: linux, azure-devops, yaml

I have a folder path trying to use a CopyFiles task in an ADO pipeline .yaml file that contains a dot like the following:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy ARM Template Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '.azure/ARMTemplates/'
```

This results in an error that the path can't be found:

```
##[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: /home/vsts/work/1/s/.azure/ARMTemplates/
```

I know I can fix this if I modify the directory to use a file structure that does *not* contain that preceding dot, so the following works successfully:

```
SourceFolder: 'azure/ARMTemplates/'
```

I believe this issue is that on Linux, a directory with a dot at the beginning is considered hidden and can not be seen by default with a directory listing. I'm not 100% sure this is the culprit, but wondering if I did want to retain that directory name of `.azure/` how can I do this in that .yaml file to either escape that dot, or use whatever syntax required to make it work and recognize the directory?

Comment: You're starting off with a seemingly unverified assumption that the path you're expecting to be there is actually present. Have you verified it? A leading dot shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Yes I could see it and it was present. All I did was change the directory name from `.azure` to `azure`, updated the path in the .yaml to reflect it and it worked. Didn't change structure or anything just the name.

Comment: What if you replace the `CopyFiles@2` with a `script: cp .azure/ARMTemplates wherever`?